# "Let we do it!" Grammatical?

Tags: subjects

Can I say

> Let we do it

Instead of

> Let's do it

One more question. Because *let's* is a contraction of *let us*, so can 'us' be a subject? Isn't 'us' only used as object?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the link, it's informative! But, Im having problem detecting the subject. :)

Comment: Note that *Let's do it!* is effectively an ***imperative***, where ***us*** is actually the syntactic "object". The implied "subject" in imperatives is usually ***You** [should] let us [do it]*, but in this case it might make more sense to imagine it as representing ***We** should let **ourselves** do it*. Having said that, I think you could run into some real difficulties trying to analyse the "grammar" of ***let's***, which is really something of a peculiar usage that obeys its own unique syntax rules.

Comment: Yes, it's difficult to analyze.  It should be treated in your grammar book under a heading like ***let*-imperatives**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/let-let-s) Dictionary values discretion over valor; it explains how and when to use the expression, but avoids analysis altogether.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, as the proposed duplicate says nothing about the construction *Let we*. We should let this question stand, since it is reasonable in its own way.

Comment: [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/84220/3463) might be helpful.

Comment: *let we do it* it's not a accepted standard English, yet it's still around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, and nope.

Subject pronouns (I, we, you, he, she, it, they) come before the verb in sentences and clauses.  (Exception is gerunds and infinitives, this is not one of those exceptions).

After the verb, if a new clause has not started for any reason, you need to use object pronouns (Me, us, you, him, her, it, them).

English imperative or "command" mood usually omits the *you* in front of the verb, which is why it's not there in "Let us X..."  It can still be included for clarity.

---

If gerunds or infinitives have subjects, then object pronouns are used (because technically they can't have subjects, I think).  If the verb doesn't end in *-ing* then you aren't using a gerund, and if *to* isn't in front of the verb, then you aren't using an infinitive.

> I walked to the park.
>
> Me walking to the park was a bad idea.
>
> We walked to the park.
>
> Us walking to the park was a bad idea.
>
> To go to school was considered the smart thing to do.
>
> Me to go to school at 2:00 is what she was planning. (I think this is correct but sounds really awkward, the gerund preferred here.)